# How to make my FreeBSD machine visible automatically on Mac within same local network?

Tags: domain-name-system, freebsd, mac, hostname, local-area-network

The Mac machines within a local network is visible automatically to the other Macs. They're visible on Finder and can be accessed with their names via console. As I know this is multicast-local-DNS.

I want to make my FreeBSD machine is visible from my Mac. I just want to connect to there with it's hostname for SSH. Is there a simple solution for this? I tried `hosts` file, but it was not a good idea because the host address are configured by DHCP so not guaranteed.

Answer (score 4):

I installed `mDNSResponder` package.

```
pkg_add -r mDNSResponder
```

And added this line on /etc/rc.conf to activate it as daemon.

```
mdnsd_enable="YES"
```

This is smallest & simplest solution.

Answer (score 3):

You can [install avahi](http://www.endeavoursofanengineer.com/blog/2010/05/08/installing-avahi-on-freebsd-2/)(/usr/ports/net/avahi).

> Avahi is a free zeroconf implementation, including a system for multicast DNS/DNS-SD service discovery. It is licensed under the GNU Lesser General Public License (LGPL).

Comment: Avahi is included in OpenBSD's Gnome desktop packages, so it must be good :-)

Comment: Avahi works good, but it's definitely stand for GUI desktop. So it has too heavy dependencies for me :(